# How transition from an Oval shape to a square?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a transition from an Oval shape to a square shape on the selected face (Screenshots are attached below), in my model. How could I do that? Sorry if I caused any inconvenience I am quite new to blender.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select all the edges on one side of the face (all the ones on one arc)
2. Hit `S then X then 0 then Enter` - this scales the edge selection to 0 on the X axis, essentially bringing them all in line
3. Move the selection to the desired position on the X axis
4. Repeat on the other side

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the geometry you want to cast to a square.
2. Assign it to a vertex group `Group`.
3. Select a face that will define the "square". <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> to snap the 3D Cursor to the center of that face.
4. In Object mode, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> to add an empty.
5. Enable snapping in *Face Project* mode, enable *Align Rotation to Target*.
6. <kbd>G</kbd> Move your empty and snap it on the same face as in p. 3. Now <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> to move it back to 3D Cursor.
7. Select the mesh object again and add a *Cast* modifier:

   - Shape: cuboid
   - Axis: `X` `Y`
   - Factor: 1.0
   - Vertex Group: `Group`
   - Size: [your choice]
   - Size from Radius disabled
   - Object: `Empty`
   - ✅ Use Transform enabled
8. Select the empty again, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> to adjust the square alignment.

[image]

Comment: That's a great way of tackling the issue! Especially if the selection is rotated.